# C# (.NET) Build Failed: the error is shown multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, build, rider

I'm wondering why whenever I have an error while compiling my code, the error is shown multiple times like this screenshot:

[image: error messages]

I'm using JetBrains Rider, Thanks :)

Comment: are you multi-targeting, i.e. targeting `net48;net6.0;net8.0` or something like that? that can happen when multi-targeting

Comment: You're right! I'm using .NET MAUI, I have a target framework for each deployable platform (android,  mac catalyst, iOS and windows) even if the framework is 8.0 for everyone. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can occur if you are multi-targeting, i.e. if you have something like:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1;net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

in your project file. The build is per-target (because `#if` and project filters may change the active code on a per-target basis), and thus you can get repeated warnings. If you scroll to the right, you *may* find the target platforms specified near the end of the message. This can also apply to target platforms.